# WCF service throws an error after application pool recycling until loading any page

Tags: wcf, impersonation

I've a WCF service that uses `MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory` to create service instances.
I noticed a strange behavior - if I recycle the application pool (or it is recycled automatically) and then call the service (via console client) it will throw an error, but after loading any page via browser everything is OK.

Here's what the client gets:

```
The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))
```

There're no errors neither in Application log nor in ULS.

I run the Sysinternals Process Monitor utility and it captured the following info:

[image]

[image]

OK, something went wrong with impersonation. I turned impersonation off, the error disappeared.

My env:

-SharePoint 2010

-Windows authentication

-Anonymous access disabled

-Impersonation enabled

Here's what my service looks like:

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    [BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class DocumentSetService : IDocumentSetService
    {
        public DocumentQueryResult SearchDocument(DocumentQuery query)
        {
            ... Code
        }
    }
```

Where is the wrong place in my configuration/code? Thx for any help.